# error occurring on docker hub image pull openshift codereddy

Tags: openshift

I have a `CodeReddy Red Hat OpenShift Container platform` cluster running on `Windows 10`.

I have docker image hosted in docker hub (public). When I try to create a `Pod` using this docker hub hosted image, it's failing om image download.

What could be possible reason?

> Internal error occurred: docker.io/ajmaly/public:latest: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.217.4.10:53: server misbehaving

The output for `Resolve-DnsName registry-1.docker.io` is below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the DNS configuration wasn't setuped properly.
[5.1. DNS configuration details](https://code-ready.github.io/crc/#dns-configuration_gsg)

The registry-1.docker.io resolves here to this IP's

```
dig +short registry-1.docker.io
34.238.187.50
54.224.119.26
34.231.251.252
107.23.149.57
3.224.96.239
3.229.227.53
18.213.137.78
3.220.36.210
```

Maybe this link could help you to fix your issue.

[Installing CodeReady Containers (OpenShift4) on Hyper-V (Win 10)](https://medium.com/@stefaan.degeyter/installing-codeready-containers-openshift4-on-hyper-v-win-10-9c8d8a510c01)

Comment: Thanks for reply. how to check registry-1.docker.io resolution? I am not sure here.

Comment: I think on windows with nslookup

Comment: Please check the edited question, I have added result for `registry-1.docker.io`, it's still giving error.

Comment: this from the host. you should look how to tell code ready on windows to send dns requests to the host